# angularjs ui bootstrap using partial view in tabs instead of simple content scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement tabs on angularjs project following [this approach](http://embed.plnkr.co/TMN3KNlS4Dv90SvbTQKJ/)

> My question is: how can I change this implementation to use separate
>   partial html view for each tab instead of  `content: "whatever"`

Comment: use directives or components for the content, then templateUrl will point to html source

Comment: Or just use tab html for navigation and set each route up with it's own template. Very simple to toggle active class yourself by putting the actual tabs html in a directive yourself